# How can i append image file to formData

Tags: reactjs, redux, file-upload, form-data, saga

I want to append image file to FormData but it is not working

```
 `let formData = new FormData();        
  let profile = data.payload;
  formData.append('avatar', profile.avatar);
```

here avatar is image file having value:

*avatar: FileList
0: File {name: "dulux.jpg", lastModified: 1592928192081, lastModifiedDate: Tue Jun 23 2020 21:03:12 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 8336, …}
length: 1
**proto**: FileList*

Comment: why it's not working? You can't see formData values in console but in request payloads

Comment: payload is empty

Comment: are you sure that `profile.avatar` is object? not array?

Comment: yes ... avatar: FileList {0: File, length: 1}

Comment: then `formData.append('avatar', profile.avatar[0]);`

Comment: working now ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your profile.avatar is an array:

```
formData.append('avatar', profile.avatar[0]);
```